# JavaScript inheritance and object properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning myself JavaScript, but I'm confused about the whole prototyping and inheritance in JavaScript.

Example 1:

```
function MyClass()  {
    this.my_var =  "1";
}

function MyClass2()  {
    this.my_var2 = "2";
}

MyClass2.prototype = new MyClass();

class2 = new MyClass2();
console.log(class2.my_var);
console.log(class2.my_var2);
```

This is the easiest one to understand. the prototype of MyClass2 is a MyClass object, so it seems natural that class2 has access to its properties.

Example 2:

I wondered if it was possible to set the prototype in the constructor function itself:

```
function MyClass()  {
    this.my_var =  "1";
}

function MyClass2()  {
    this.my_var2 = "2";
    this.prototype = new MyClass();
}

class2 = new MyClass2();
console.log(class2.my_var);
console.log(class2.my_var2);
```

This doesn't seem to work however. my_var appears to be undefined.

Example 3:

Let's try another approach, this time using Object.create():

```
function MyClass()  {
    this.my_var =  "1";
}

function MyClass2()  {
    this.my_var2 = "2";
}

MyClass2.prototype = Object.create(MyClass);

class2 = new MyClass2();
console.log(class2.my_var);
console.log(class2.my_var2);
```

No luck either, my_var appears to be undefined.

Example 4:

This time, I'm using NodeJS "inherits()" function from the "util" module:

```
util = require("util");
function MyClass()  {
    this.my_var =  "1";
}

function MyClass2()  {
    this.my_var2 = "2";
}

util.inherits(MyClass2, MyClass);

class2 = new MyClass2();
console.log(class2.my_var);
console.log(class2.my_var2);
```

I understand why example 1 works, but I don't understand why 2,3 and 4 do not. I hope someone can explain me why that is the case.

Comment: You can use `this.__proto__ = new MyClass();`

Comment: 2 doesn't work because `this` is just a regular object, so `.prototype` does nothing special. 3 doesn't work because you should be using `Object.create(MyClass.prototype)` and using `.apply` to in `MyClass2` to invoke `MyClass` on `this`.

Comment: @jcubic that is probably not the best solution. Using `Object.create` seems more sensible.

Comment: @jcubic it is not advised to manipulate ```__proto__```. Do it only for learning.

Answer (score 1):

Example 2:
`this` keyword is reference to instance of an object. That is object created with `new`. You can't set prototype in a constructor because object's `prototype` is used as a prototype for creating new object when using `new` keyword. So... `MyClass`'s prototype is used when creating new object, and `this` references some object that is `instanceof` `MyClass`.

`.prototype` property is specific to function and it is an object that is copied to instanced object of that function/class.

Example 3:
`Object.create()` creates object from another object, and you pass in function which may be an object but you get not clone of an object but of a function object. But you want object that is an instance of a function/class.

so if you type: `Object.create(MyClass).__proto__` you'll see it is a function. `__proto__` is special internal object prototype represents after evaluating your script. You can manipulate for experiments but it is not advised to manipulate it in production. You can fix this example by using `new MyClass`.

Example 4:
You need to add `MyClass.call(this);` as first line in `MyClass2` function.

Answer (score 0):

The first is actually wrong, because you should be inheriting from `MyClass`'s *prototype*, and not from an instance of it.   Although this was commonly done in the past, it's a broken inheritance model that expects you to create an instance of an class before you can derive subclasses from it.

From there, it follows that the other examples are also wrong because in each case you're still inheriting from an instance (in cases two and three) or expecting that non-prototype properties of the base class will be visible in the derived class (case four).

The correct formulation for case three is:

```
function MyClass() {
}

MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() { ... }

function MyClass2() {
    MyClass.call(this);     // invoke superclass constructor
}

// create a new (empty) prototype that chains to the superclass's
MyClass2.prototype = Object.create(MyClass.prototype);

// and reattach the constructor
MyClass2.prototype.constructor = MyClass2;

// now add methods to MyClass2
MyClass2.prototype.myMethod2 = function() { ... }
```

Comment: Why is the first one wrong? I don't think its a good approach, but he is inheriting from `MyClass`'s prototype via the instance.

Comment: @squint it's wrong because it conflates the properties of that single instance with the methods that should be in its prototype.  It also makes it impossible to invoke a superclass constructor properly.

Comment: That could be a way to set primitive defaults on `MyClass2.prototype`. Again, I wouldn't do it but with respect to how inheritance works, it's not incorrect. WRT calls to the superclass' constructor, did you mean the subclass?

Comment: @squint no, I meant the superclass - in my version here the derived class's constructor makes a call to the superclass's constructor.   If you've derived from an instance there's no superclass constructor to call because the (singe) instance has already been constructed.

Comment: Okay, it seems that I'm even more confused than I initially thought. Since JS doesn't really have "classes", I was unaware that there are also constructors involved. So initialisation of an object occurs in two different places? constructor and prototype?

Comment: @Alnitak: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. You can still use the same `MyClass.call(this)` and any properties added will shadow the defaults on `MyClass2.prototype`.

Comment: @JeroenJacobs The `MyClass` function _is_ the constructor (and actually JS does now have classes in ES2015).   The prototype is where methods shared between all instances are stored (and the prototype chain is where the shared methods of the superclass[es] are found)

Comment: @squint so at that point you're both inheriting from the instance _and_ calling the parent constructor explicitly too?  Yikes.

Comment: with ```MyClass.call(this)``` you are only calling ```MyClass``` as a function and passing ```this``` as another ```this``` (subclassed instance). That is, manually calling superclass' constructor. Which you should do.

Comment: @Alnitak: Why is that Yikes? You're doing the same thing with `MyClass2.prototype = Object.create(MyClass.prototype)`. Your way creates the exact same prototype chain, minus the default property being added.

Comment: @squint in the "instance based" model if you call the parent class from the base class constructor then you end up with the base class properties in both the prototype and the (derived) instance.   In the "Object.create" version the instance properties and the prototype properties remain separate.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been saying. You get those "default" properties on the `.prototype`, which may or may not be desired but once you do `MyClass.call(this)`, they'll be shadowed anyway, if the logic in `MyClass` allows it. Don't get me wrong. Your way is much better IMO, but it has more to do with potentially harmful side effects in the constructor when called to create the `.prototype`. Other than that, they're basically identical.

Comment: I think we're in violent agreement.   My main issue is that you shouldn't have to invoke the parent constructor (and trigger any side effects it may have) merely to set up the parent / child relationship.

Comment: LOL, yeah, my only disagreement is with saying it's wrong. Since the question is about inheritance, that seems confusing. I figured you knew how it worked so parts of your answer left my scratching my head. :-)